# How to transfer textbox to another page in Windows Phone 8.1-C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Hi guys I am new to app development and was wondeing how to transfer a textbox that holds a value to another page. My code is below:

**Basket Button**

```
 private void Confirm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Confirmation) , Totaltxt_TextChanged = TotalValue); 

    }
```

**The OnNav in which information needs being sent to**

```
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Basket Basket = e.Parameter as Basket;

        if (Basket != null) 
        {
            COsttxt.Text = string.Format("{0:C}", Basket.Totaltxt_TextChanged);
        }
    }
```

I have tried with just TotalValue which is the main value that needs to be sent but that seem to work I even set it in the textbox of the NavTo page:

```
        <TextBox x:Name="COsttxt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="58" Margin="229,258,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TotalValue}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="131" TextChanged="COsttxt_TextChanged"/>
```

So is there a way to just send the Totaltxt textbox from Basket.xaml and make the textbox value display in Confirmation.xaml?

Comment: Use this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh702394.aspx method form.

Comment: Thanks for the help but that doesnt really specify on how to send textboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a parameter to Confirmation page which I am sure is not of type Basket and hence you are getting null when you do `as` conversion.

You should be simply passing/reading TotalValue this way:

```
private void Confirm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Confirmation) , TotalValue);
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var totalValue = e.Parameter as string; // or 'as' whatever is type of TotalValue

    if (totalValue != null) 
    {
        COsttxt.Text = string.Format("{0:C}", totalValue);
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Pass the final textbox value as below and keep rest of the code same:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Confirmation) , textboxName.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the type is not string it is a double and when I change it to a double an error occurs , I have changed it to -  double totalValue = e.Parameter as double;  and error is still there.

Comment: You cannot use `as` for Value types, only for Reference ones. Use `Convert.ToDouble(e.Parameter)` instead.

Comment: It does transfer the information but it doesnt send the exact information in the textbox i.e. when I apply discount to the TotalValue the textbox updates, is there a way where the textbox in one xml be sent to another with that exact figure.

Comment: Not sure what is it that you don't understand. It is very straight forward. See my **Edit**.